# how to make a bitcoin buy with euros on Kraken API

Tags: kraken

I am trying to use the kraken api to make bitcoin buys with euros, I am looking at the API here
https://www.kraken.com/help/api

But I am here with some doubts

```
("pair => "XXBTZEUR",
"type" => "buy",
"ordertype" => "market",
"voulme" => ?
)
```

Witch volume should I put there ? volume in BTC or Euro ? 
I wish I could put euros there, but I am not sure, theres no specification on the api about this

Answer (score 2):

Found how to do it, we shoud use the oflags

```
oflags = comma delimited list of order flags (optional):
    viqc = volume in quote currency (not available for leveraged orders)
    fcib = prefer fee in base currency
    fciq = prefer fee in quote currency
    nompp = no market price protection
    post = post only order (available when ordertype = limit)
```

In this case:

```
("pair => "XXBTZEUR",
"type" => "buy",
"ordertype" => "market",
"voulme" => '10',
"oflags" => "viqc"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use "viqc" option as described in the Kraken API documentation but got this error:
{"error":["EAPI:Feature disabled:viqc"]}

I searched the web and found this reddit link:
https://www.reddit.com/r/KrakenSupport/comments/e0hc08/rest_api_create_a_market_order_for_xrpeur/

> Despite being mentioned in our REST API documentation, the viqc order option is not presently available for any order type

I think it's a shame they did not mention this on their documentation. It's taken me plenty of time to understand why this was not working.